# Regex to match all lowercase character except some words

Tags: regex, python-3.x

I would like to write a RE to match all lowercase characters and words (special characters and symbols should not match), so like [a-z]+ EXCEPT the two words `true` and `false`.

I'm going to use it with Python.

I've written `(?!true|false\b)\b[a-z]+`, it works but it does not recognise lowercase characters following an uppercase one (e.g.  with "This" it doesn't match "his"). I don't know how to include also this kind of match.

For instance:

- `true & G(asymbol) & false` should match only `asymbol`
- `true & G(asymbol) & anothersymbol` should match only `[asymbol, anothersymbol]`
- `asymbolUbsymbol | false` should match only `[asymbol, bsymbol]`

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to remove `\b` (word boundary) and use a negative lookbehind in your regex as this:

```
(?<![a-z])(?!true|false)[a-z]+
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/uek4PA/2)

**RegEx Details:**

- `(?<![a-z])`: Assert that we don't have a lowercase letter at the left
- `(?!true|false)`: Assert that we don't have `true` or `false` at the right
- `[a-z]+`: Match 1+ lowercase characters

Comment: it looks that works, but I don't understand why `(?<![a-z])` is needed.

Comment: It is needed to avoid matching in the middle of a lowercase word. e.g  it avoids matching `rue` in word `true`

Answer (score 0):

I would create two regexes (you want to mix word boundary matching with optionally splitting words apart, which is, AFAIK not straighforward mixable, you would have to re-phrase your regex either without word boundaries or without splitting):

- first regex: `[a-z]+`
- second regex: `\b(?!true|false)[a-z]+`